# Lines added to output text file

Tags: visual-studio, fortran, fortran77, intel-fortran

I am compiling a Fortran 77 project with Visual Studio 2008 using Intel Fortran 2013 and I am having a stupid issue in one of the output file created by the executable.
In this file, I am expect to read something like

```
EXPECT FILE :
"
foo1
foo2
"
```

instead, I obtained almost the same but with empty lines lines in between:

```
OBTAINED FILE:
"
foo1

foo2
"
```

This can seem like a detail but it is actually a problem as this file is read by another program which is not checking for the empty lines.
The strange thing is that I also compiled this under Linux and the problem does not appear, that's why I concluded it is necessarily a Visual Studio option issue.

---

The source code looks like this :

```
character*80 comment(2)

comment(1)="foo1"
comment(2)="foo2"

do i=1, 2
 write(10,*)comment(i)
end do
```

---

I tried to change several options inside the Fortran Properties but none of them did work

Anyone having some idea about this ?

Comment: Can you check that you do really have blank lines, rather than just lots (say 76) of blanks at the end of each line?

Answer (score 1):

This is (most likely) because the string is printed including all 80 characters, i.e., even with the trailing spaces (as suggested in the comments). One can observe this directly by putting the string being printed in quotes:

```
WRITE(10, '(A)') "'"//comment(i)//"'"
```

One solution would be to use, e.g.,

```
WRITE(10, '(A)') TRIM(ADJUSTL(comment(i)))
```

Here, `ADJUSTL` would remove also leading spaces. If this is not desirable, one could use just `TRIM`.